# WPF WebBrowser control doesn't open links

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I have a `Grid` , with 2 `Popup` children.
The first `Popup` has a single `WebBrowser` child (used as a tooltip) , and the second `Popup` has a single `ListBox` child (used as auto-complete suggest box).

When I display HTML in the `WebBrowser` (using NavigateToString) with `<a href="...">` tags, the links appear underlined but nothing happens when I click them.

This is how I defined the first `Popup`:

```
<Popup 
    x:Name="ToolTip" 
    StaysOpen="False"
    IsOpen="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=SomeClass}"
    AllowsTransparency="False"
    PopupAnimation="None"
    Placement="Absolute"
    Height="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=SomeClass}"
    Width="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=SomeClass}"
    HorizontalOffset="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=SomeClass}"
    VerticalOffset="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=SomeClass}"
       >
    <Border 
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75"
            Background="Black">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <WebBrowser Name="ToolTipBrowser"/>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

And, in order to open links in new windows, I added this method:

```
private void TooltipBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Uri != null)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, at a first look i notice in your WebBrowser definition the Navigating property missing, so change it to this and see if it works:

    `<WebBrowser Name="ToolTipBrowser" Navigating="ToolTipBrowser_Navigating"/>`

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks, I have it in the code but I didn't paste it